# Identify Border Style Cell Excel

Tags: excel, vba, formatting, border

I'm trying to figure out the particular border style of cell within a workbook that I received. The normal way to do this would be ctrl+1->Border and look at the style. However, the style for this particular cell is blanked out and I suspect that the border is formatted using a proprietary style. How do I get the properties of this border style (I guess with VBA?) in order to set up my own macro which then applies this particular border style to other cells?

I hope someone can help me out here.

EDIT:

[image]

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.border(object)

Comment: Thanks Michael for sending this across. I've looked already at the document before and am not able to figure out how to implement it in such a way that it works on my side, I guess this has to do with my relative inexperience with VBA. Could you help me out with a small VBA code to set up what I want (identify the specific border style)? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you need to add bold white borders to the left and right-hand sides of the cell to generate the effect.

Comment: I was already thinking about that, but with my Excel, it had no effect. It has, however, if you select the double line (lineStyle=xlDouble)

Answer (score 3):

In Excel, select the cell with the border in question.

Change to the VBE environment (Alt+F11). Open the Immediate Window (Ctrl+G).
Type in the immediate window:

```
? ActiveCell.Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle
```

And

```
? ActiveCell.Borders(xlEdgeBottom).Weight
```

Compare the values with the documentation:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xllinestyle
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlborderweight

It would surprise me it one of the two values cannot be found in the lists.

Comment: Thanks Thomas, this is helpful but still not getting me what I need. I edited my original Question by adding a picture. What I would like to get are these "less" wider borders than what is the "standard" width for borders. Do you have any idea how to figure out / set these "widths" to different lengths? thanks

Comment: No clue, never saw that. Are the values for LineStyle and Weight the same for both cells? When you copy the format of the cell with the format painter, is the strange looking border copied?

Comment: Yes the values for LineStyle and Weight are the same for both cells. And also, yes, when I copy the format with the format painter, the strange looking border is copied and I can just not figure out what the underlying properties of the weird looking border are.

Comment: Is there any content in the strange looking cell? (e.g. white chars on white background?)

Comment: Yes, but even when changed the border stays the same. I can do all I want with the cell in terms of formatting but as long as I do not change the border style the style keeps being there.